# Statistical Model: How much will my open bar at my wedding cost?

Tags: prediction, model

I am getting married in November in Mexico and after fidgeting with my wedding budget, I was wondering if anyone had any insight into how I should approach my problem. Thought it was relatively interesting enough to open it up to this community.

I need to forecast/budget my open bar costs for my wedding. The objective would be to have some form of a model that I can say with a reasonable prediction interval, that my open bar costs will be X.

Here is the information I have available to me.

- Number of Guests: 120
- male/female ratio: ~50%
- 25-35 yrs old moderate drinkers: 75%
- 55+ light drinkers: 25%
- Weather: 70-80 degrees/beach
- Drink costs:

  - Water/Soda: \$3
  - Beer \$5
  - Wine/Liquor: \$10
- Duration:

  - Wedding: 6 hours
  - Bar: 5 hourse

Average drink rates I have found online is one drink an hour but open to other suggestions based on better/more informed research.

Anyone have any thoughts? I have done some basic statistical regressions and models, but am a novice.

Feel free to ask questions and I will do my best to answer them.

Comment: This won't benefit much from statistical analysis: the answer will be only as good as the estimates you have found online and the degree to which they might apply to your particular guests in Mexico. Any answer must also depend on the consequences of exceeding or falling short of the budgeted amount. If there are no important consequences of exceeding the budget, then why bother; and if there are important consequences, then maybe you should be spending your energy finding creative ways to place a hard cap on this expense.

Comment: I agree with the comment above - potentially what might help you to think about your challenge is though a simulation of different potential outcomes, based on your estimates / probability distributions of the individual variables that you have outlined. you could easiy do this in R, or, if you want to use Excel, you can download e.g. CrystalBall to run some basic simulations or sensitivity analyses. Let me know if not clear - ignore if not helpful

Comment: Thanks for the comments. In terms of the consequences, there are not large issues if I exceed my budget. But after playing around with different methods I could think of for trying to answer the question, I thought it be interesting to hear how others might approach this. Wouter described much of my previous efforts (potential outcomes and probability distributions). I will have a look at Crystalball which I have not used before. Thanks again for both responses!

Answer (score 3):

One could use Monte Carlo and some reasonable prior assumptions to quantify the uncertainty in your costs, at the least.

Here I make some very rough assumptions:

- Guests will drink at a steady pace for all six hours
- We pretend we've seen six guests, four of which were moderate drinkers, two were light drinkers.
- Moderate drinkers consume 1 per hour (sd = .3)
- Light drinkers consume .5 per hour (sd = .2)
- We pretend we've seen twenty-five drinks served: five sodas, ten beers, ten wine/liquor.
- No guest will earn you money by consuming negative beverages.

```
library(truncnorm) # for truncated normal, so guests don't have drinks<0

library(gtools) # for dirichlet prior, water vs beer vs wine

total.cost = NULL
# begin Monte Carlo loop
for (i in 1:1e4) {
  guests = 120
  prices = c(3, 5, 10)
  hours = 6
  # get number of men
  prob.male  = rbeta(1, 30, 30) # prior distribution, contains uncertainty
  n.male = rbinom(1, size = guests, prob = prob.male) 
  n.female = guests - n.male
  # get number of moderate/light drinkers
  prob.moderate = rbeta(1, 4, 2) # prior distribution, contains uncertainty
  n.moderate = rbinom(1, size = guests, prob = prob.moderate)
  n.light = guests - n.moderate
  # make rate of drinks/hour
  rate.moderate = rtruncnorm(n.moderate, a=0, mean=1, sd=.3)
  rate.light = rtruncnorm(n.light, a=0, mean = .5, sd = .2)
  rate.guests = c(rate.moderate, rate.light)
  # weights for preference water/soda vs beer vs wine/liquor
  drink.probs = rdirichlet(1, alpha=c(5, 10, 10)) # prior, contains    uncertainty

  # how many drinks?
  drinks.total = sum(rate.guests * hours)
  drinks.expense = prices %*% rmultinom(1, size=drinks.total, prob=drink.probs)

  # store drinks expense to vector
  total.cost = c(total.cost, drinks.expense)
}

summary(total.cost)
hist(total.cost)
```

[image: MCMC distribution]

You can see there's a lot of uncertainty, even in this crude model. You might expand the uncertainty further by better modeling of your prior assumptions.

Comment: You can see I'm struggling a little bit with the formatting -- StackExchange thinks my R comments should be markdown headers. Edits would be appreciated.

Comment: Fixed the formatting by throwing in an HTML comment; the parser gets confused by code immediately following a list.

Comment: The model you describe is within the range in which I was guessing as well.  The assumptions you made were inline with my same thoughts (SD estimates etc).  My current estimate fell within the same line.  Somewhere between the 4-5K mark is where I think it will land.  Are there any know Monte Carlo/Monte Carlo light simulators available online somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

With 120 guests you could make a rough guess for each individual and then total them.  A lot of the underestimates will be balanced out by overestimates.

I did that sort of thing using pen and paper for my wedding.  For each relative, I had my mother tell me whether she thought that person would definitely or probably come or not come and calculated an expected number.  If I remember correctly (40 years ago!), my estimate turned out to be with 10 people of the actual number that showed up.

Comment: In terms of attendance, i already performed an expected estimate.  The 120 is that number.  After reviewing the list of guests, i researched estimates for guest probability for destination weddings and discovered that was 60-65%.  I then went through each person and asked the question with my financee, if that person was 25%/50%/75% or 100% likely to come.  After inputting that information and summing it all up, lo and behold it was nearly identical.